# FederationIdentifier: Converting lists to maps

Tags: soql

Using 2 separate lists to hold ownerId and its associated federatedId.

1) I am trying to convert these 2 lists into single map collection that can hold both. But confused on how to add ownerId to key of map. Right now as ownerId is list, I am using `ownerId.add`

2) Below code works perfectly fine except that when I do `system.debug(agentId)` I see nothing as agentId is list. I tried using `agentId[0]` but still unable to get the value. Please suggest me corrections as I am looking to avoid writing another `for` loop

```
list<case> c1 = [SELECT Id, ownerId from case Limit 1];
list<Id> ownerIds = new list<Id>();
list<string> agentId = new list<string>();

for(case c: c1){
    ownerIds.add(c.ownerid);
    system.debug(c.ownerId);
    system.debug(agentId);
}

list<user> u1 = [select Id, name, federationidentifier from user where Id In :ownerIds];
for(user u : u1){
    agentId.add(u.federationidentifier);
}
system.debug(agentId);
```

Comment: Do any of the users identified by the ownerId have a federationidentifier value? Try adding `system.debug(agencyId.size());` and `system.assertNotEquals(0, u1.size());`

Comment: All users I am querying have federationIdentifier. I double checked with size as per your suggestion.

Comment: What's the final map going to be then? A map from the user id to the federationidentifier?

Comment: thats correct martin.. I want a map of userid/ownerid and their federationidentifier..

Comment: Also, in the code I put in question, since agentId is a list, I am unable to get the value of it when I do system.debug(agentId).

Comment: Is this being run in a test or some other setting where there might not be any cases returned? What are you getting for your first two debug statements?

Comment: first one is just a placeholder to display ownerId and 2nd is where I am trying to get federationId

Answer (score 2):

```
List<case> c1 = [select id, ownerid, owner.name, owner.federationidentifer from case limit 1];
Map<id,string> ownerIdToFederationIdentifer = new Map<ID, String>();
for (case c : c1) {
    ownerIdToFederationIdentifer.put(c.ownerid, c.owner.federationidentifer);
}
System.debug(ownerIdToFederationIdentifer);
```

If you are doing this in a sandbox you may have no data, which would result in the empty map.

Comment: Thanks Doug. owner.federationidentifier cannot be queried I believe. I tried that and also mentioned on Question: 47467 here on SOF. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you can't query it, then you won't be able to put it in a list or a map

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler didn't warn you when you tried to run your code. I've been getting: "No such column 'federationidentifer' on entity 'Name'."

Comment: As you can see in pmvsdt original, he is able to compile and run selecting federationidentifier from user.

Comment: The code I have in my question works perfectly fine martin except that I want to combine those 2 lists in one map...

Comment: after working on that federationidentifier, I found that it can be queried only from user not using relationship fields from case

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the map from owner/user id to FederationIdentifier.

```
map<Id,String> maptofederationid = new map<Id,String>();
list<Id> ownerIds = new list<Id>();

list<case> c1 = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Case LIMIT 1];

for(case c: c1){
    ownerIds.add(c.ownerid);
}

list<user> u1 = [select Id, Name, FederationIdentifier from user where Id IN :ownerIds];

for (User u : u1) {
    maptofederationid.put(u.Id, u.FederationIdentifier);
}

system.debug(maptofederationid);
```

Comment: Martin, please add `system.debug(maptofederationid.get(c.ownerid));` after ownerIds.add inside for loop and it is returning null. If you check in the last system.debug you will notice that all those ownerIds have federationIds

Comment: @pmvsdt That's normal. At that point in the code, maptofederationid is just an empty container. Nothing gets put into it until the second loop.

Comment: so is there a way for me to get the value inside the for loop ?

Comment: @pmvsdt Not in the first for loop, no; the federation identifier hasn't been queried for yet.